# Python reading in integers from a csv file into a list

Tags: python, list, csv

[image]I am having some trouble trying to read a particular column in a csv file into a list in Python. Below is an example of my csv file:

```
Col 1       Col 2
1,000,000   1
  500,000   2
  250,000   3
```

Basically I am wanting to add column 1 into a list as integer values and am having a lot of trouble doing so. I have tried:

```
for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
    list = [int(row.split(',')[0]) for row in csvfile]
```

However, I get a ValueError that says "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"1'

I then tried:

```
for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
    list = [(row.split(',')[0]) for row in csvfile]
```

This time I don't get an error however, I  get the list:

```
['"1', '"500', '"250']
```

I have also tried changing the delimiter:

```
for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
    list = [(row.split(' ')[0]) for row in csvfile]
```

This almost gives me the desired list however, the list includes the second column as well as, "\n" after each value:

```
['"1,000,000", 1\n', etc...]
```

If anyone could help me fix this it would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Please post your CSV file (or just link to it), so we can produce the same results.

Comment: The separator is commas, could that be the problem?

Comment: If your data contains commas, you can't use comma as separator

Comment: Just noticed that this is a well asked question, so +1!

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: The desired output would be ['1,000,000' , '500,000', '250,000'] P.S. these values would also need to be integers

Comment: What if you replace `row.split(',')[0]` with just `row[0]`? The commas are *already split* by the `csv.reader`

Comment: I have just given that a go however, it only adds the first number into the list so it looks like: [1, 5, 2] as oppose to [1,000,000, 500,000, 250,000]

Comment: Normally, a csv file can use quoting is a delimiter (or a new line) is embedded in a field, so just rely on the scv module to give you fields and just forget `split`. And please show the actual content of the csv file (in a text editor, `cat` on linux, `type` on Windows) and NOT in a spreadsheet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should choose your delimiter wisely :
If you have floating numbers using `.`, use `,` delimiter, or if you use `,` for floating numbers, use `;` as delimiter.

Moreover, as referred by [the doc for `csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) you can use the `delimiter=` argument to define your delimiter, like so:

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    mylist = []
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';'):
        mylist.append(row[0]) # careful here with [0]
```

or short version:

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    mylist = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')]
```

To parse your number to a float, you will have to do

```
 float(row[0].replace(',', ''))
```

Comment: he has spaces in the csv header

Comment: It's not really a float though and float won't really parse things like `1,000,000` without extra steps.

Comment: Everything is actually wrong with spaces, tab is the most sane option if you don't use a comma or a semicolon. You can theoretically use any whitespace but handling whitespace-containing strings becomes complicated if you do. You should quote your strings anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file and split at the space using regular expressions:

```
import re
file_data = [re.split('\s+', i.strip('\n')) for i in open('filename.csv')]
final_data = [int(i[0]) for i in file_data[1:]]
```

Comment: Yep. No reason to do weird regexp stuff when you have a whole special library built specifically to read csv.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must parse your data correctly. Because it's not, in fact, CSV (Comma-Separated Values) but rather TSV (Tab-Separated) of which you should inform CSV reader (I'm assuming it's tab but you can theoretically use any whitespace with a few tweaks):

```py
for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="\t"):
```

Second of all, you should strip your integer values of any commas as they don't add new information. After that, they can be easily parsed with `int()`:

```
int(row[0].replace(',', ''))
```

Third of all, you really really should not iterate the same list twice. Either use a list comprehension **or** normal `for` loop, not both at the same time with the same variable. For example, with list comprehension:

```
csvfile = StringIO("Col 1\tCol 2\n1,000,000\t1\n500,000\t2\n250,000\t3\n")
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="\t")
next(reader, None)  # skip the header
lst = [int(row[0].replace(',', '')) for row in reader]
```

Or with normal iteration:

```
csvfile = StringIO("Col 1\tCol 2\n1,000,000\t1\n500,000\t2\n250,000\t3\n")
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="\t")
lst = []
for i, row in enumerate(reader):
    if i == 0:
        continue  # your custom header-handling code here
    lst.append(int(row[0].replace(',', '')))
```

In both cases, `lst` is set to `[1000000, 500000, 250000]` as it should. Enjoy.

By the way, using reserved keyword `list` as a variable is an extremely bad idea.

UPDATE. There's one more option that I find interesting. Instead of setting the delimiter explicitly you can use `csv.Sniffer` to detect it e.g.:

```
csvdata = "Col 1\tCol 2\n1,000,000\t1\n500,000\t2\n250,000\t3\n"
csvfile = StringIO(csvdata)
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvdata)
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect=dialect)
```

and then just like the snippets above. This will continue working even if you replace tabs with semicolons or commas (would require quotes around your weird integers) or, possibly, something else.