# Reading specific row/column from csv using python

Tags: python, pandas

```
[mean],"2466.3564356435645","2460.980198019802","2469.019801980198","2463.3168316831684","2468.207920792079",
```

above is my data generated from `netlogo` (huge file). I want to make list for creating box wiskers for the data only from this column with header "mean". How can I do it and how to remove these `"` and `,` in the generated list. Thanks

Comment: can you post your desired output plz?

Comment: 2466.3564356435645,2460.980198019802,2469.019801980198,2463.31683168,2468.207920792079
I want to generate such list from which i can draw wisker box. I have 9 such files and would like to embed them all in one i.e. 9 wisker box.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, it is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47457362/python-reading-in-integers-from-a-csv-file-into-a-list?rq=1), among other places, with some tweaks depending on your data and your csv:

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    mylist = [float(row[0]) for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')]
```